# Unable to use aws lambda consumer with MSK in cross account mode

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-kafka, aws-lambda, aws-msk

I have an MSK cluster setup from kafka team in an aws account which we are using for publishing and consuming messages from topics. Currently, we have ec2 based java application, in our dev aws account that are consuming the messages.  MSK cluster and our EC2 based applications are in different account and they use MTLS to authenticate and communicate.

However, we wanted to explore aws lambda consumers for MSK cluster. However, the event source for aws lambda doesn't seems to like the arn of the MSK cluster due to cross account.  Is there a way around it without using VPC peering.  We currently have VPC Link setup for accessing Kafka cluster.

I have churned through all the examples given by AWS for using lambda consumer but all these examples has both the cluster and lambda sitting in same account. Any help would be greatly appreicated.

I am also trying to look at this solution https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs-cross-account-example.html which gives and example of accessing SQS event source from a different account. Will post my results soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create Lambda Event Source Mapping to MSK from another account.

Instead, you can [create Lambda ESM to Apache Kafka](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-kafka.html). When you select Apache Kafka as a source, you will need to provide VPC config where you will be running your Lambda (and ESM), the bootstrap URL of your cluster (instead of ARN of MSK), and ensure the connectivity between two VPCs (including Security groups configuration on both sides for inbound and outbound rules).

Comment: Hi @EdbE, Thanks for your help. I followed the documentation for connecting to MSK as self managed apache kafka.  I got it working after setting up Private Links for lambda and STS ( i dont have auth atm). Also, i had to explicity enable the trigger after creating lambda.

Comment: To All & @EdbE, Please be informed that AWS has released new MSK integration for cross account clients. Here is the blog post for the same https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/connect-kafka-client-applications-securely-to-your-amazon-msk-cluster-from-different-vpcs-and-aws-accounts/.  Unfortunately, this released just when i got the solution working with private VPC endpoints. :(

Comment: Yes, multi-vpc is available now! but it is only within a single region - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/msk/latest/developerguide/aws-access-mult-vpc.html . If you are planning on cross-region access, you still need to have Apache Kafka trigger in addition to all the networking setup.